# ng model inside ng-repeat of ng-repeat-start

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following structure parent can have multiple children and children will have an objective. I need to show this in editable table, but when I bind the model within the input of objective, it updates all other selected children's objective too.

here is
[code](https://plnkr.co/edit/2z2XOFwYrHZp1gpcnYZ5?p=preview)

select same childrens from two row's options, and edit the objective of one children it will reflect in other row as well.

```
<tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat-start="parent in records" ng-class-even="'striped'">
            <!--KPI-->
            <td><strong>{{parent.name}}</strong></td>
            <!-- controls -->
            <td tool-tips class="inputs">
                <select
                        ng-model="parent.childrens"
                        ng-options="item as item.name for item in controlTypes"
                        multiple='multiple'>
                </select>
            </td>
            <!-- Controls objective-->
            <td colspan="1"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-if="parent.childrens.length>0"
            ng-repeat="child in parent.childrens">
            <td name="process" colspan="2" style="word-wrap:break-all;" align="right">{{child.name}}
            </td>
            <!-- Controls objective-->
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="ultra-short" ng-model="child.objective"
                       maxlength="200"/>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat-end></tr>
        </tbody>
```

Any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell it woun't work with such structure, because all you do is work with references. When you change some options `objective` property you actually change it everywhere in same option, because you are working with reference.

**UPDATE:**
[One way](https://plnkr.co/edit/gjJQiUBsdztGGlWmXSNh?p=preview) to handle this

Comment: What is the proper way to solve this scenario? I have used @Nikhilish K V solution. Don't know what is $rootIndex but it creates an undefined propety in parent and I can access the childrens using paren[parentIndex].undefined.childrens[index].objective. definitely it is not solution but at moment used at urgency.

Comment: While it(2-way binding) works with nested ng-repeat, is it the problem with ng-repeat-start only?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the model to be different for each iteration of the ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="parent in parents">
  <select
    ng-model="vm.model.parent.item"
    ng-options="item as item.name for item in controlTypes"
    multiple="multiple">
  </select>
</div>
```

Now you have a different model for each iteration, is this what you were looking to do?

Comment: Did you selected the options in two row and try to edit the objective. problem is not select, I want the objective of children to be set in the correspoinding parent